# Mock/Test Super class call in subclass..is it possible?

Tags: unit-testing, seam, mockito, easymock, jmock

I am looking for a solution to mock the super call in subclass ButtonClicker.

```
Class Click {
      public void buttonClick() throws java.lang.Exception { /* compiled code */ }     } 

Class ButtonClicker extends Click { 
    @Override
    public void buttonClick() throws Exception {

        super.buttonClick();
    } }
```

Comment: Please be a bit clearer when you ask a question. Please elaborate....

Comment: I can't think of a use case where mocking ButtonClicker's 'buttonClick' method wouldn't meet your needs - can you explain your case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using inheritance reduces testability of your code. Consider replacing inheritance with the [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) and mock the delegate.

Extract the interface IClicker

```
interface IClicker {
    void buttonClick();
}
```

Implement `IClicker` in `Clicker` class. In case that you are working with third-party code consider using [Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Rewrite your `ButtonClicker` as following:

```
class ButtonClicker implements IClicker {
    Clicker delegate;

    ButtonClicker(Clicker delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public void buttonClick() throws Exception {
        delegate.buttonClick();
    }

}
```

Now just pass the mock as a constructor parameter:

```
Clicker mock = Mockito.mock(Clicker.class);
// stubbing here
ButtonClicker buttonClicker = new ButtonClicker(mock);
```

Comment: Thanks for putting down the code, It is legacy code which am trying to test-cover, however am considering to refactor it now, have couple of more questions though. 
1. Class Click is a third party code, could you please explain why I should consider Adapter and NOT delegation. I see even with delegation,  I just need modify my class ButtonClicker implementing an Interface. 
2. ButtonClicker is actually an action bean(seam component), which is called directly from UI, I wonder how/when the one argument ButtonClicker constructor will be called for delegate to call methods of class Click?

Comment: In case that you would not use ButtonClicker as Clicker you can skip extracting interface IClicker

Answer (score 3):

The answer is no.  A mock is only a trivial interface implementation.  (I mean interface in the API sense, not the specific Java keyword sense.)  So it doesn't know about any implementation details like which class actually implements the functionality (there is no functionality, essentially).

You can create a 'spy' on a real object that will let you mock only some methods and not others, but that also will not let you mock just the super method of a class because the method(s) you choose to mock are typically chosen by the signature, which is the same for both the sub class and the super class.

Comment: yeah I tried `ButtonClicker spy = Mockito.spy(new ButtonClicker());
        Mockito.doNothing().when((Clicker)spy).buttonClick();
        spy.buttonClick();` even this dint let me mock the super method call.